# iPad Crash Type Unknown Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm getting the following crash labeled as Type Unknown on an iPad using MonoTouch.  It generally happens after using the app for some time.  We have a Navigation Controller that is used to push and pop from 1 view to the next.  So basically, MainView->DetailView and back.  We can trigger this to occur by switching between views rapidly, but it will occur over time as well.

```
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 6.0 (10A403)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Sun Aug 19 00:29:38 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2107.2.33~4/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8945X
Date:                2012-09-27 16:19:58 -0700
Time since snapshot: 112 ms

Free pages:        4271
Active pages:      41877
Inactive pages:    27069
Throttled pages:   137163
Purgeable pages:   85899
Wired pages:       36984
Largest process:   TabletApp

Processes
Name                    <UUID>                       rpages       recent_max           [reason]          (state)

BlueTool <e0940958fde030c4983b25d7b4e2ad67>          239              239                          (daemon) (idle)
CommCenterClassi <c82f228b14a830cdb88e3cc1068330b3>          740              740                          (daemon) (idle)
timed <f3f0e010a9a13ae69b5761a5db3f4a3c>          532              532                      (daemon) (idle)
geod <73e79779d11a312cb70c3770e494ceab>          464              464                      (daemon) (idle)
afcd <b0aff2e7952e34a9882fec81a8dcdbb2>          194              194                      (daemon) (idle)
notification_pro <845b7beebc8538ca9ceef731031983b7>          242              242                      (daemon) (idle)
mobile_assertion <018ee854c7b6344ba5094f83827fee1c>          249              249                      (daemon) (idle)
afcd <b0aff2e7952e34a9882fec81a8dcdbb2>          211              211                      (daemon) (idle)
coresymbolicatio <edba67001f76313b992056c712153b4b>          173              173                      (daemon) (idle)
installd <309cd72e8af43ad1b77d96274d0b0ff7>          454              454                      (daemon) (idle)
xpcd <2190623b9f8033b3a3323e50385f952e>          190              190                      (daemon) (idle)
gamed <5e2c4c3e9ef03bbba60e09baecc38a72>         1155             1155                      (daemon) (idle)
networkd_privile <f8858e6f66af39ab8ce8f105cfa6872f>          167              167                      (daemon) (idle)
softwareupdatese <2bc4b5ae016431c98d3b34f81027d0ae>          678              678                      (daemon) (idle)
deleted <1135432740b43f699975b1fd8bffa05f>          350              350                      (daemon) (idle)
assetsd <52be6deaa7cb326bb0b5a58cd43d3771>         2439             2439                      (daemon) (idle)
lsd <6a9f5b5f36b23fc78f87b6d8f1f49a9d>          596              596                      (daemon) (idle)
AppleIDAuthAgent <29029c5fc04736c99a0846fa84f03f3b>          273              273                      (daemon) (idle)
itunesstored <4e0cd9f873de3435b4119c48b2d6d13d>         1911             1911                      (daemon) (idle)
accountsd <ac0fce15c1a2350d951efc498d521ac7>         1606             1606                      (daemon) (idle)
MobileMail <bff817c61ce33c85a43ea9a6c98c29f5>         1932             1932                      (resume) (continuous)
mstreamd <b0ff7a57c8393a399b920e9fb6ba1ce3>         1678             1678                      (daemon)
kbd <3e7136ddcefc3d77a01499db593466cd>          871              871                      (daemon)
tccd <eb5ddcf533663f8d987d67cae6a4c4ea>          239              239                      (daemon)
TabletApp <991649f8252c30fb880c779b532e2deb>       166400           166400  [per-process-limit] (frontmost) (resume)
mediaserverd <80657170daca32c9b8f3a6b1faac43a2>         2548             2548                      (daemon)
locationd <892cd1c9ffa43c99a82dba197be5f09e>         1457             1457                      (daemon)
wifid <9472b090746237998cdbb9b34f090d0c>          963              963                      (daemon)
syslogd <cbef142fa0a839f0885afb693fb169c3>          409              409                      (daemon)
iaptransportd <f784f30dc09d32078d87b450e8113ef6>          371              371                      (daemon)
SpringBoard <27372aae101f3bbc87804edc10314af3>        18297            18297                     
backboardd <5037235f295b33eda98eb5c72c098858>       129351           129351                      (daemon)
fseventsd <996cc4ca03793184aea8d781b55bce08>         1173             1173                      (daemon)
imagent <1e68080947be352590ce96b7a1d07b2f>          618              618                      (daemon)
mDNSResponder <3e557693f3073697a58da6d27a827d97>          456              456                      (daemon)
filecoordination <fbab576f37a63b56a1039153fc1aa7d8>          242              242                      (daemon)
absinthed.J1 <1143ac2f5558356f9e807c21457e999a>          263              263                      (daemon)
lockdownd <ba1358c7a8003f1b91af7d5f58dd5bbe>          560              560                      (daemon)
powerd <2d2ffed5e69638aeba1b92ef124ed861>          333              333                      (daemon)
eapolclient <6fe4832769b3315c93072b4d0fed42b7>          324              324                      (daemon)
UserEventAgent <6edfd8d8dba23187b05772dcdfc94f90>          974              974                      (daemon)
networkd <0032f46009f53a6c80973fe153d1a588>          345              345                      (daemon)
aggregated <8c3c991dc4153bc38aee1e841864d088>          160              160                      (daemon)
SCHelper <2cb7ad29b9873115857da94ca4666547>          257              257                      (daemon)
BTServer <c92fbd7488e63be99ec9dbd05824f5e5>          777              777                      (daemon)
configd <4245d73a9e96360399452cf6b8671844>          759              759                      (daemon)
distnoted <a89af76ec8633ac2bbe99bc2b7964bb0>          292              292                      (daemon)
fairplayd.J1 <a39944b046c43c2a92bc1dff62ff04d3>         1112             1112                      (daemon)
apsd <94d8051dd5f5362f82d775bc279ae608>          601              601                      (daemon)
notifyd <51c0e03da8a93ac8a595442fcaac531f>          213              213                      (daemon)
**End**
```

Does any one know what this error could mean?  Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try deploying a debug version on the device then start the app in debug mode from MonoDevelop, you may identify at least the source line crashing.

Comment: Is anything printed to the device console when this happens? My guess is that you're getting several memory warnings, and your app is eventually terminated. The best tool to figure out memory problems is Instruments (launch it from Xcode's menu -> Open Developer Tool -> Instruments).

Comment: This is from a debug build, and there is nothing on the device console that seems relevant. I've tried running instruments and it seems like memory is being consumed at an alarming rate... but I'm not sure how to fix that.  The objects that are being created and not properly removed seem to be objects from internal ios classes that are not being created from me (or at least anywhere I know of).